# Using Google Apps Script to save a single sheet from a spreadsheet as pdf in a specific folder

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am using a Google spreadsheet to prepare invoices and was looking for a simple script that saves a sheet, where the invoice is in, in a "invoices" folder to build an archive.
I "borrowed" code from numerous contributors on Stackoverflow and youtube and came up with a code that works. I had to copy the invoice to a newly created spreadsheet, because it seems to be impossible to create a pdf from one single sheet in type spreadsheet. I also had to use a piece of code to move the pdf from the root to an "invoices" folder
The only thing I am not able to solve is that the spreadsheet created in line 6 consistes of 2 sheets. An empty one and a correctly copied one. The created pdf thus alsa has 2 sheets, one empty and one correct sheet.
Anyone got a clue how to solve this ? 
By the way sometimes it takes some minutes before the pdf shows in the folders.

Below is the code

```
function generatePdf(){
    //Create a temporary spreadsheet, to store the desired sheet from the spreadsheet in. 
    var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    originalSpreadsheet.setActiveSheet(originalSpreadsheet.getSheets()[4]);
    var name = "Testname"
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
    //Save the desired sheet as pdf
    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
    var saveCopy = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
    //Delete temporary spreadsheet
    DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next().setTrashed(true);
    //Move the pdf file from the rootfolder to the folder where invoices are to be stored.
    var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B3ok04PZOVbgLXA2dy14MVlLRXM");
        destination.addFile(file);
        var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
        pull.removeFile(file);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if you have encountered this code but you can try this:

```
function checkSheet() {
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
var folderID = "FOLDER_ID"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
var pdfName = "Invoice "+Date();

var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

//Copy whole spreadsheet
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

//delete redundant sheets
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
}
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

//save to pdf
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

//Delete the temporary sheet
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

***Note***:
While testing this code, it creates the pdf in an instant, but it may depend on the invoice template.

References:

- [Simple Google Apps Script to export a single sheet to PDF and email it to a contact list](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885)
- [Sample Template - Professional Invoice Template](https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AhQ4K4pgicTxdHlFajM1MG1IbkI3X2FNMG92NnNzbFE&mode=public&ddrp=1#) (for Testing Purpose)

Hope this helps!

## UPDATE

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks it almost worked for me. A "pdfish" file was created, a pdf logo showed but the filename had no pdf suffix and could not be opened. I changed two lines: i deleted .setName etc. from the line: var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName); and replaced "tmp_convert_to_pdf" in line var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder)) by pdfName. And now it works fine. Thanks agian for your help.

Comment: Thanks, for your help, it led me to a solution to my problem and it works like it should.

Comment: I know it's been 7+ years, yet now there is a better code at "https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/", not mine, just found by Luck. @Mr.Rebot many thanks for the code. Would have stayed there but for my number of sheets it took ...forever.