# Margins parameters for Google spreadsheet export as PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, url, query-string

I need the margins parameter to export my spreadsheet as a pdf.

I've searched for information about setting the margins parameter and can't find anything.  The following parameters are working well.

```
var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A4'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id
```

Answer (score 53):

Actually, it's possible to set the margins and create a PDF. You just need to know the names of the parameters and their possible values. I've have got it to work with these

**Parameters:**

```js
&format=pdf                   //export format
&size=a4                      //A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
&portrait=false               //true= Potrait / false= Landscape
&scale=1                      //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
&top_margin=0.00              //All four margins must be set!
&bottom_margin=0.00           //All four margins must be set!
&left_margin=0.00             //All four margins must be set!
&right_margin=0.00            //All four margins must be set!
&gridlines=false              //true/false
&printnotes=false             //true/false
&pageorder=2                  //1= Down, then over / 2= Over, then down
&horizontal_alignment=CENTER  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
&vertical_alignment=TOP       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
&printtitle=false             //true/false
&sheetnames=false             //true/false
&fzr=false                    //true/false
&fzc=false                    //true/false
&attachment=false             //true/false
```

As you can see there are more parameters for PDF formatting than currently known circulating around the Internet. Yes, it seems like they are not documented by Google.

If PDF export fails, it's probably an incorrect value. Some parameters do not have an effect on the Export. For example: your are using `source=labnol`, this is not a "real" parameter but it doesn't cause any trouble.

Make sure you have all four margin parameters inside your url like this:

`&top_margin=0.00&bottom_margin=0.00&left_margin=0.00&right_margin=0.00`

Otherwise it won't create the PDF.

Comment: @Mr How did you find these?

Comment: I was able to identify  `&gid=0` to print only the first sheet of the document, or a specific sheet. (found by trial and error. I haven't tried comma separated ids of sheets, this might work as well)

Comment: This needs to get way more votes. There are a lot of gaps in documentation regarding App Script and something as simple as setting margins shouldn'tve taken 3 days of research (and delayed a project by 3 days).

Comment: Does anyone know which parameter to use to print the date at the bottom of the page?

Comment: One tip - remember that the margin setting is always in inches regardless of your settings,

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that it is possible to download a range as a PDF directly through URL options. You don't have to create a temporary sheet.

The URL options seem to be:

```
&r1 // first row to print: 0-indexed 
&r2 // last row to print: 1-indexed 
    // this seems inconsistent; maybe it is technically the first row that is 
    // not printed, 0-indexed

&c1 // first column to print: 0-indexed 
&c2 // last column to print: 1-indexed (see above)
```

These URL options are included in the code on [this page](https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/)