# Python Google Sheets api export to pdf with 0" margin

Tags: python, pdf, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

I can effectively export to PDF from a google sheet using this code

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gDriveCreds="mycreds.txt"

gauth = GoogleAuth()
GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = "client_secrets.json"
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(gDriveCreds)
if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    gauth.Authorize()
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(gDriveCreds)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file_obj = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'sfkldjlfsdkjfgdklj'})
file_obj.GetContentFile('temp.pdf', mimetype='application/pdf')
```

But I can't figure out a way to create the pdf with 0" margins like I want. I have the google sheet set up with 0" margins, but the python export just defaults to some typical margin.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312255/9337071