# How to horizontally align a Google Sheet using export URL parameters?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to use URL parameters to horizontally/vertically align a sheet when exporting it to a PDF? Something like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oAvIn28488l95xiMZPt_dLJebcT3jqoaQZ9axdIpDGw/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid=582165762&horizontalAlignment=center
```

I've tried several variations of this but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What does that even mean? You can set the alignment of rows & columns with Apps Script prior to exporting (be sure to flush after altering).

Comment: @tehhowch I mean the way the sheet displays as a PDF when it's exported. The sheet is always aligned to the left of the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088042/margins-parameters-for-spreadsheet-export). The parameter I was looking for was `&horizontal_alignment=CENTER`.