# Setting pdf export options in google drive for python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, export-to-pdf

I am downloading a google spreadsheet as a pdf using this command.

```
    response = files_service.files().export_media( fileId=spreadsheet_id,                                                   mimeType='application/pdf').execute()

    with open("download.pdf", "wb") as wer:
        wer.write(response)
```

Which downloads the file as pdf. However, I need to set the orientation to landscape, custom margins, and custom footer. How do I set it with google drive API v3?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to export Google Spreadsheet as a custom PDF file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In order to export the custom PDF file, this sample script uses `requests.get()`. Please think of this as just one of them.

#### About access token:

In this sample script, the access token is used. From your script, you are using `files_service.files().export_media()`. So I thought that you have already used `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)` as shown in [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). In this case, you can retrieve the access token as follows.

```
accessToken = creds.token
```

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please replace your script to the following script. In this sample script, the orientation to landscape, custom margins and the page number at the footer can be set.

```
accessToken = creds.token
spreadsheetId = '### Spreadsheet ID ###'
sheetId = '0' # sheetId
url = ('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId + '/export?'
       + 'format=pdf'  # export as PDF
       + '&portrait=false'  # landscape
       + '&top_margin=0.00'  # Margin
       + '&bottom_margin=0.00'  # Margin
       + '&left_margin=0.00'  # Margin
       + '&right_margin=0.00'  # Margin
       + '&pagenum=RIGHT'  # Put page number to right of footer
       + '&gid=' + sheetId  # sheetId
       + '&access_token=' + accessToken)  # access token
r = requests.get(url)
with open('downloadedPDFfile.pdf', 'wb') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(r.content)
print('Done.')
```

- `accessToken = creds.token` is access token.
- Please set Spreadsheet ID to `spreadsheetId = '### Spreadsheet ID ###'`.
- Please set each parameter as the query parameters.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no query parameters for setting the custom footer using when the Spreadsheet is manually exported, yet. I apologize for this situation. About other query parameters, you can see them at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088042/margins-parameters-for-spreadsheet-export).
- If you want to export all sheets in a Spreadsheet, please remove `'&gid=' + sheetId`.

#### Reference:

- [margins parameters for spreadsheet export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088042/margins-parameters-for-spreadsheet-export)

  - In this thread, the query parameters for exporting Spreadsheet are shown.

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I will use the url directly.

Comment: @user61034 Thank you for replying. I apologize my answer was not resolved your question. Can I ask you about your current issue? If my script has issues, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @user61034 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.