# Export a Google sheet as PDF setting parameters such as margin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to export a specific sheet in my spreadsheet to a PDF file, the file will be set a name based on cell values and I want to set export settings so that all margins are set as 0

I got the below code online and have modified it to suit my needs but the export doesn't bring through the file name as I would like and it doesn't set the export margins to 0 and fit to page:

Has anyone got any ideas of how I can do this through apps script (if someone has a better script i'm open to trying that :) )

```
function exportPDF() { 
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Agreement");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Agreement");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var name = sheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var company = sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var order = sheet.getRange("C11").getValue();
  var gAcc = sheet.getRange("C12").getValue();
  var pdfName = "Agreement_" & name;

  if(company != "")
  {
    pdfName = pdfName + "_" & company & "_" & order & "_" & gAcc;
  }
  else
  {
    pdfName = pdfName + "_" & order & "_" & gAcc;
  }

  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:I57");
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you read [margins parameters for spreadsheet export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46088042/1330560)? Does it help?

Comment: _but the export doesn't bring through the file name as I would like_ Would you please expand on this. In what way is the file name not as you would like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The filename is achieved by rearranging your code, and properly concatenating some strings.

I have modified your script in several places, as follows:

```js
function exportPDF() { 

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Agreement");

  var name = sourceSheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var company = sourceSheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var order = sourceSheet.getRange("C11").getValue();
  var gAcc = sourceSheet.getRange("C12").getValue();
  var pdfName = "Agreement_" + name;

  if(company != "")
  {
    pdfName = pdfName + "_" + company + "_" + order + "_" + gAcc;
  }
  else
  {
    pdfName = pdfName + "_" + order + "_" + gAcc;
  }

  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  var folder;
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
     folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(pdfName, folder))

  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.setActiveSelection(sourceRange.getA1Notation());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  var theBlob = getBlob();
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob).setName(pdfName);

  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Up to here you have created a pdf with the data that you want, and the name you want. But the margins are still not what you want.

---

#### Setting the pdf margins:

Get the blob using `UrlFetchApp`

```js
function getBlob(){
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/';
  var id = '<YOUR-FILE-ID>';
  var url_ext = '/export?'
  +'format=pdf'
  +'&size=a4'                      //A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
  +'&portrait=true'                //true= Potrait / false= Landscape
  +'&scale=1'                      //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
  +'&top_margin=0.00'              //All four margins must be set!
  +'&bottom_margin=0.00'           //All four margins must be set!
  +'&left_margin=0.00'             //All four margins must be set!
  +'&right_margin=0.00'            //All four margins must be set!
  +'&gridlines=true'               //true/false
  +'&printnotes=false'             //true/false
  +'&pageorder=2'                  //1= Down, then over / 2= Over, then down
  +'&horizontal_alignment=LEFT'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
  +'&vertical_alignment=TOP'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
  +'&printtitle=false'             //true/false
  +'&sheetnames=false'             //true/false
  +'&fzr=false'                    //true/false
  +'&fzc=false'                    //true/false
  +'&attachment=false'
  +'&gid=0';
  // console.log(url+id+url_ext);
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+id+url_ext).getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  return blob;
}
```

---

#### There you have it. A pdf without margins exported from a sheet.

**Note:** *To avoid authenticating when using `UrlFetchApp` you can make your sheet public*

Comment: Can you provide a documentation link for those url parameters, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a long time on how to get the scale factor aka zoom (in 5th scale mode, i.e. custom in the GUI).

`spct` (scale percent, e.g. 1.3 for 130%) which must be used in conjunction with `scale=5` parameter.

Looking like `...&scale=5&spct=1.3&...`

Comment: As a workaround, could setting scale to fit width/height and then modifying the margins work?

Comment: @MattBowyer I have tried that option, but did not work as expected.
Modifying the margin could only provide more usable space for hidden cells to appear in the usable area, not to zoom/scale.
No matter what option I tried (scale={1..4}), it did not provide any zoom effect.