# Define specific area to Generate PDF - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, pdf, pdf-generation, auto-generate

In this case I have an annoying problem. I can't control a specific area to be a PDF format. Every time I execute the code, the result is like this:[current preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7jKP.png)

But I'm expecting the result is like this: [let's say B2:G23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ds60.png)

Here is the code:

```
function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=7' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=true' //  repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
    + '&ir=false'
    + '&ic=false'
    + '&r1=0'
    + '&c1=0'
    + '&r2=24'
    + '&c2=8'
```

Hopefully someone could solve my problem

Thank You!

I'm expecting the result is like this: [let's say B2:G23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ds60.png)

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what the expected result is? The image you provided isn't even of pdf

Comment: What about changing the `r1` and `c1` parameters? If `r1` is for “*row start*” then why would you set it to 0 if you want B2 to be the left upper corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a PDF file from the cells "B2:G23" of `sheetName` using your showing script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, by `;` of `+ '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id`, the scripts just after the line of this are not run.
- When you want to export the cells "B2:G23", it is required to be `r1=1&c1=1&r2=23&c2=7`. It seems that the 1st index is 0.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=7' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=true' //  repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId() // the sheet's Id
    + '&ir=false'
    + '&ic=false'
    + '&r1=1'
    + '&c1=1'
    + '&r2=23'
    + '&c2=7';

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName(pdfName));
}
```

- When this script is run, a PDF file is created into the root folder.

#### References:

- [Margins parameters for Google spreadsheet export as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46088042/7108653)
- [exportSpreadsheet.gs by andrewroberts](https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/c37d45619d5661cab078be2a3f2fd2bb)
- [exportSpreadsheet.gs by Spencer-Easton](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! It works! Just remove a single ';' and it's done. Once again, thank you for your insight. I'm a big fan of you :)