# Display the PDF version of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I want to display the PDF version of google sheet. I have tried with

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yp55fNmcrPQ96eggHpVTEFDCSIUcxEFGnK-TTmv111o/export?format=pdf&embedded=true
```

The examples here are https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be

Comment: The sheet must be public

Comment: Or if you have a access token, try adding `&access_token=[TOKEN]`

Comment: Displays server error 500 when access_token is embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are using the correct syntax to display a public Spreadsheet as a pdf

For my sample sheet as below it works:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hnx_EWPN3Djs9tOIjfOt0R7XC3bsn66uLdTBxmlQAx8/export?format=pdf&embedded=true

> If it is not working for you, either

- The document is not spreadsheet
- The id is not correct
- The sharing permissions are not sufficient - try to set it as Public on the web
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways to get PDF of the sheet.

[Google apps script getAs('application/pdf') layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209619/google-apps-script-getasapplication-pdf-layout) wil help.

Then you can open it in iframe.

EDIT:
You should publish your spreadsheet before using displaying it.

In your spreadsheet, select `Menu > File > Publish` To The Web.

You'll see this window.
[image]

Select desired range to publish and file type.

Then, they provides a link to share/embed etc.

Comment: The question is not about creating PDF, Its displaying PDF version from the link.