# Exporting Sheets to PDF using getAs('application/pdf') returns unexpected margins & formatting

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, type-conversion

I converted Google Sheets file to PDF with scripts:

```
var source = DriveApp.getFilesByName('template').next();
var temp = source.getAs('application/pdf').setName(new_name);
var newFile = folder.createFile(temp);
```

Unfortunately the destination file PDF lost all margins it originally had.
I have set the correct margins in Google Sheets.

How do I keep the same margin values in the destination file?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211625/7215091

Comment: look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088042/margins-parameters-for-spreadsheet-export/46312255)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google apps script getAs('application/pdf') layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209619/google-apps-script-getasapplication-pdf-layout)