# Google Apps Script : Download PDF responses from Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have created a Google form with few responses. I want to download those responses as PDF format into my local pc using a script run by Apps Script. I can't find any apis in Apps Script to do so.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check if the issue was still affecting you?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Form, it will save your responses in a Sheet, [as described here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en). You can export that sheet as PDF following step 2 in [this tutorial](https://oregonstate.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=45811) using the UI.

If you want to use GAS, you can follow [this tutorial](https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/), to show you how to create an add-on for it. You can also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706318/11581830) to get a single sheet as a PDF.

However, I believe the suggestion of doing it with the UI will work best for you, since each form has only that Spreadsheet associated to it, and it will have only one sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try and give the feedback.